# How to convert set of chacraters into ASCII and print the character that repeted odd number of times using SCALA

Tags: scala

Need to convert set of characters into ASCII.

Ex: `AABccdE` - then result should be `66`

Tried as below:

```
var word = args(0)
var asc = word.map(x => x -> x.toByte)
```

Comment: in `AABccdE`, `B`, `d` and `E` appear odd number of times (1). how are you expecting 66 only? not `66`, `99`, and `69`

Comment: Need to print the character that is occurring max odd number of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val s = "AABBBccdE"
s.distinct.map(c=>(c,s.count(_==c))).filter(_._2%2==1).maxBy(_._2)._1.toByte
```

**In Scala REPL:**

```
scala> s.distinct.map(c=>(c,s.count(_==c))).filter(_._2%2==1).maxBy(_._2)._1.toByte
res65: Byte = 66
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you have an input

```
val input = "AABBBccdE"
```

where the character B is appearing max odd number of times. Then you can get the ASCII value of that character by

```
input.groupBy(identity)
     .collect{ case (k,v) => (k -> v.size) }
     .toList
     .filter(x => x._2%2==1)
     .maxBy(_._2)
     ._1
     .toByte
```

This will fetch an output as

```
res0: Byte = 66
```

Comment: Why `collect`? `map` does the job here without the overhead of checking for defined-ness.